# Passing R functions to C routines using rcpp

Tags: r, rcpp

I have a C function from a down-stream library that I call in C like this

```
result = cfunction(input_function)
```

`input_function` is a callback that needs to have the following structure

```
double input_function(const double &x)
{
  return(x*x);
}
```

Where `x*x` is a user-defined computation that is usually much more complicated.  I'd like to wrap `cfunction` using Rcpp so that the R user could call it on arbitrary R functions.

```
NumericVector rfunction(Function F){

  NumericVector result(1);

  // MAGIC THAT I DON'T KNOW HOW TO DO
  // SOMEHOW TURN F INTO COMPATIBLE input_funcion

  result[0] = cfunction(input_function);

  return(result);
  }
```

The R user then might do `rfunction(function(x) {x*x})` and get the right result.

I am aware that calling R functions within `cfunction` will kill the speed but I figure that I can figure out how to pass compiled functions later on.  I'd just like to get this part working.

The closest thing I can find that does what I need is this https://sites.google.com/site/andrassali/computing/user-supplied-functions-in-rcppgsl which wraps a function that uses callback that has an oh-so-useful second parameter within which I could stuff the R function.

Advice would be gratefully received.

Comment: I am a little unsure as what it is that you want.  `Rcpp::XPtr` allows you to wrap user-supplied C functions, and my `RcppDE` package is worked example (allowing the compiled differential evolution to work with a user-supplied C function as the objective function).  There are other questions and answers here too.

Comment: Oh, and if it is just an R Function things are *much* simpler -- look into existing examples for `Rcpp::Function`.

Comment: I can't change the source code of cfunction. As far as I can tell, I somehow have to coerce the `Rcpp::Function` to a `double foo(const double &x)` so that cfunction can call it. That's the part I am struggling with.

Comment: The objective function in the link I posted is almost there and it uses the mechanisms you allude to but my objective function doesn't have that `void *p` parameter.  I'll look again at the examples you mention and see what I can do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution would be saving the R-function into a global variable and defining a function that uses that global variable. Example implementation where I use an anonymous namespace to make the variable known only within the compilation unit:

```cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>

extern "C" {
    double cfunction(double (*input_function)(const double&)) {
        return input_function(42);
    }
}

namespace {
std::unique_ptr<Rcpp::Function> func;
}

double input_function(const double &x) {
    Rcpp::NumericVector result = (*func)(x);
    return result(0);
}


// [[Rcpp::export]]
double rfunction(Rcpp::Function F){
    func = std::make_unique<Rcpp::Function>(F);
    return cfunction(input_function);
}

/*** R
rfunction(sqrt)
rfunction(log)
*/
```

Output:

```r
> Rcpp::sourceCpp('57137507/code.cpp')

> rfunction(sqrt)
[1] 6.480741

> rfunction(log)
[1] 3.73767
```

Comment: Is there an alternative without resorting to a global variable?

Comment: In line `func = std::make_unique<Rcpp::Function>(F);` I get: "no member named 'make_unique' in namespace ''std, expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction"

Comment: @rmagno Your compiler does not use C++11. Try to add `// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]`. As for solutions without a global variable: They might exist, but none has come to my mind yet. And nobody posted an alternative solution.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It seems it's just Rstudio syntax diagnostics bugging me.